# Why do I get "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': #<Promise> could not be cloned error" when using Promise of iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, promise, postmessage

I've got host web application that loading another part of the same application with same domain within an iframe. My code looks like the following:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const api = iframe.contentWindow.api;

const result = await api.performAsyncAction().then(response => response.json());
```

After executing the code above I've got the following error message:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': #<Promise> could not be cloned.
```

Could you please help me with that kind of error? I'm aware of postMessage utilizing to communicate between iframe and host application but I need to figure out why the error above being thrown (I'm a bit surprised as I don't use postMessage here)

**UPDATE**:

`performAsyncAction` method is implemented likes the following:

```
function performAsyncAction () {
  return fetch("/api/request", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json'   
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: Please show us how `performAsyncAction` is implemented.

Comment: Well do you use postMessage somewhere else?

Comment: @Bergi Please see my updated post

Comment: @epascarello, nope I don't use postMessage at all

Comment: I suspect that `fetch` is patched, not the original one. pls show us the full error stack, need more context.

Comment: @hackape hmm I don't add any patches for fetch. I only utilize import `babel-polyfill` that utilizes `postMessage` but I don't see any patches for initial `fetch`